# How to getPar and setPar to access the guts of par()

Tags: r, plot, variadic-functions, getter-setter

I am working on some generic accessor functions for the `par()` option in R.

### getPar

```
getPar = function(key)
    {
    par()[[key]];   
    }
```

This works as expected.

```
getPar("mar");
```

### setPar

```
# save memory ... restoreState ... pdf 
setPar = function(key, val)
    {
    # par(mar=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
    # R.O. indicates read-only arguments: These may only be used in queries and cannot be set. ("cin", "cra", "csi", "cxy", "din" and "page" are always read-only.)
    # https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/par
    pnames = names( par(no.readonly = TRUE) );
    if(is.element(key, pnames))
        {
        par()[[key]] = val;
        }
    }
```

This one does not work:

```
mar = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
setPar("mar", mar);
```

And throws an error:

```
Error in par()[[key]] = val : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Any ideas on how I can write a `setter` function as outlined?

Yes, I understand, I can pass `par(mar = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))` directly to "set" the value.  I am specifically looking for a solution that will work inside this simple `setter` function.  A variadic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment to lists (i.e., `[<-` and `[[<-`) requires an *object* on the LHS of the assignment, not an expression that produces the list. Similarly,

```r
A <- list(a=1)
A$b <- 2
A
# $a
# [1] 1
# $b
# [1] 2
list(a=1)$b <- 3
# Error in list(a = 1)$b <- 3 : 
#   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I suggest you change `setPar` to actually set the value using `par`, not try to operate on the list.

```r
setPar = function(key, val)
    {
    # par(mar=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
    # R.O. indicates read-only arguments: These may only be used in queries and cannot be set. ("cin", "cra", "csi", "cxy", "din" and "page" are always read-only.)
    # https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/par
    pnames = names( par(no.readonly = TRUE) );
    if(is.element(key, pnames))
        {
        par(setNames(list(val), key))
        }
    }

par("mar")
# [1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
setPar("mar", 1:4)
par("mar")
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: So it appears `getPar` and `par` return the same thing, and I can remove that "list-access" idea as well.

Comment: Yes, your `getPar` is equivalent to `par`. However, if you really want to get in the weeds, `par(key)` is almost 4x faster than `par()[[key]]`, and otherwise perfectly equivalent. Even the slower `par()[[key]]` is taking on the order of 34 microseconds on my machine, so this is not a critical fail-point of code. Try `bench::mark(par("mar"), par()[["mar"]])` to see the fuller comparison.

Comment: When we talk about `efficiency`, timing benchmarks are only one factor.  Less cognitive load is an important factor as well.

Comment: I agree fully. What you call "cognitive load", I usually lump into *maintainability* (for me) and *readability* (for others and for future-me), which are both (imo) reasonable reasons to intentionally avoid true performance improvments using obfuscated or obscure code-golf reductions in code. (Unfortunately, sometimes my readability has a measurable level of frustration when the load is multiplied by 3M rows ...). But yes, you are right, and that's why I suggested that shaving a few microseconds was not worth it if you prefer the former code.

Comment: I am in complete agreement.  Maybe naming the function something more verbose like `getParKey` will reduce my future 'cognitive load'.  R is awesome, but also quirky, as your answer demonstrates.  Sometimes it follows abstract algebra rules of inverse functions, and a wrapper `get/set` is easier to write: ```getAttribute = function(key, obj)
 {
 attributes(obj)[[key]]; 
 }
 
setAttribute = function(key, value, obj)
 {
 attributes(obj)[[key]] = value; 
 obj;  # no object referencing, so I must return
 }```